# Changing previous commit titles without using --force or --force-with-lease

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-commit, git-reset

Here's what happened:

1. Forked a private GH repo
2. Made some minor changes and committed
3. Made some other changes, committed and pushed to (my) `master` branch
4. Created a PR

The problem is that the commits are supposed to follow a certain format to hook up w/Jira's stories and can't be merged to the original repository unless they **ALL** follow this format.

I managed to amend the previous commit using `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, but...

*force push to master is disabled for this repo (and my fork) anyway*

Is there a way to "start over" on a PR or a particular commit without using force push? It's such a small change I'm ok with just starting over and (apparently) never ever making a mistake in the commit message again because they appear to be impossible to push even to a fork?

All I want to do is change just one penultimate commit title. How can I accomlpish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create branch on top of your current (rewritten) master, push that branch and make a new PR from that newly pushed branch.

A PR should always be make from a custom "fix/feature" branch anyway, never from master (or any branch already existing in the original repo).

That allows you to rebase locally your PR branch on top of `upstream/master` (`upstream` being the name of the remote referencing the URL of the original repo), before pushing said PR branch (and you can force push it too, if needed).
That ensures the PR will be applied cleanly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

Git commit messages can be updated by the following command. It opens up your default editor where you can change the commit title.

git commit --amend